# Replace ASP.NET RequestValidator handling with custom action filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

The framework I'm using is ASP.NET MVC 5. When the user submits forms/query strings containing potentially malicious code the application generates HttpRequestValidationException.

My current code catches this exception in Application_Error and performs a redirect to an error view that informs the user of the problems with the submission. The issue is that some of the requests expect an MVC View to be returned, while others expect a Json Response.

```
    protected void Application_Error()
    {
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();

        if (exception is HttpRequestValidationException)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Server.ClearError();
            Response.Redirect("~/Error/UnsafeRequest");
            return;
        }
    }
```

The solution I'm thinking of is to replace the default validation that takes place in the model binding phase with an action filter that contains the same logic but can be more adaptive depending on the situation (different redirects for example).

Is this at all possible or am I just on the wrong path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try this code custom action filter:

```
public class CustomFilterAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{ 
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
         if(filterContext.Exception is HttpRequestValidationException)
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary{
                    { "action", "UnsafeRequest" },
                    { "controller", "Error" }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution. I was able to get the action return type in the OnException handler and redirect to the Json response if the expected returned type is JsonResult or Task<JsonResult>

Answer (score 1):

You can condition the response with a header value like "Accept"...

```
if (Request.Headers["Accept"].Count() > 0 && Request.Headers["Accept"] == "application/json")
{
    //Create your JSON response...
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Error/UnsafeRequest");
}
```

Comment: This is not the solution I was striving for but it works for now so thank you very much !!
Do you happen to know why Azure is taking so long to throw HttpRequestValidationException? When I enter invalid input the response usually takes ~30seconds (valid input is 1-2sec)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. To test the code I had to throw my own HttpRequestValidationException... :)